# XAML - Binding to DataContext and using converter?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding

To bind to the current DataContext in XAML you can use:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
```

How do you do this using a converter in the mix?
The following works when you have a property on the path:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty,Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
```

But I dont want to do that; I just want to Bind to the datacontext and not the datacontext.MyProperty if you get what I mean.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Simply omit the path:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
```

Ah wait - I notice your question is tagged with Silverlight. Does this not work in Silverlight? If not, you may need to use the expanded syntax:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Converter="{StaticResource converter}" />
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: sigh, that easy. I had left the comma in there which broke it. 
The 1st one did the trick

Comment: Excellent - I never quite know with Silverlight. Sometimes things that seem very fundamental in WPF are completely absent in Siverlight.

Comment: Hehe I just did exactly the same thing. Wasted a good 20 minutes on a stupid comma. Thank god for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Dot sign also provide DataContext Binding for SL developers

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.,Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
```