# In Xaml what mean DataContext="{Binding}"

Tags: .net, xaml

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1338757) means the binding is done with the current DataContext. What is the current DataContext ?

Answer (score 2):

`DataContext="{Binding}"` is useless, because that's the default. A control inherits the data context of its parent. So, what happens here is that you assign the current value of the `DataContext` to itself. And that's the value your control inherited from its parent control.

Comment: The container of my combobox is a tab. The parent of my combobox is UserControl.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `DataContext` on a control says, "This is the data that I want you and your child controls to bind to." You should not add a binding on the DataContext. You add a binding on any other property, and then set the DataContext to the object you wish to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

The current DataContext is whatever you have set it to.